# Android Honeycomb: Off-center button text - unable to center

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a problem with centering text on buttons in a layout that I am working on. Please see the screenshot below (taken within eclipse's "Graphical Layout" tab):

[image: Button Text Problem]

I'm not sure what's causing this. I tried playing around with the individual layout properties of the buttons, but this has not had any effect. The following is my layout hierarchy:

```
LinearLayout (orientation is "vertical")
    ...
    RelativeLayout
        Button ("MM/DD/YYYY")
        Button ("HH:MM")
        TextView ("to")
        Button ("MM/DD/YYYY")
        Button ("HH:MM")
    ...
    LinearLayout (orientation is "horizontal")
        Button ("Close"; layout_weight is "1")
        Button ("Reserve Room"; layout_weight is "1")
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="1024dp"
    android:layout_height="640dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    ...
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dateTimePickersLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startingDateButton"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/mm_dd_yyyy" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/endingTimeButton"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/hh_mm" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/endingDateButton"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/endingTimeButton"
            android:text="@string/mm_dd_yyyy" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startingTimeButton"
            android:layout_width="244dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startingDateButton"
            android:text="@string/hh_mm" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/to"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    ...
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/closeButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/close" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reserveRoomButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/reserve_room" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone have any ideas what may be causing this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Add remaining XML.  The parts above are working fine for me.

Comment: Well, if I take out all remaining XML, I still have the problem :( I'm starting to think that it's an eclipse bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up updating eclipse and that fixed the problem. I was extremely disappointed that restarting the IDE did not change anything, especially since the XML had not posed any problems for others. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: mine just started doing this, even in the widgets tool box text is off to the right side.  It renders fine when I run my app in the emulator or on the phone, just the layout editor shows it as messed up.   I've got Juno, it just started today.  Based on what you've said, looks like I may just have to reinstall eclipse.   fail

Comment: That will fix it for sure. I don't know how the issue came about and was never able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the width of your buttons at the bottom is set to 0dp. Also make sure that their parent LinearLayout has a width set to match_parent.

Comment: I have both of these settings correct. The issue is that all of the buttons seem to have the problem (including the date and time ones). Even if I add a new button anywhere within my layout, the text defaults to being off-centered. Here's my top-level LinearLayout code: `<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="1024dp"
    android:layout_height="640dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >`

Comment: Does it look right when running on the device? It could just be a bug in ADT itself.